# Why is it necessary to break at this example?

Tags: python

I was trying to make my own way to solve finding product of a,b,c for a+b+c = 1000 and a^2 + b^2 = c^2.

I did end up finding the method by myself, however it lead me to another question about how this thing is working.

```
a= 1
b= 2
c= 997
product = 0

while a < 333:
    while c > b:
        if a**2 + b**2 == c**2:
            product = a * b * c
            break
        else:
            c += -1
            b += 1
    else:
        a += 1
        b = a + 1
        c = 1000 - a - b
    if product > 0:
        break

print (product)
```

My first attempt didn't include

```
if product > 0:
    break
```

For some reason, my code won't finish and run forever. so I just decided to add it at the end it worked. That is great. but, I'm wondering why a break is necessary there.

Doesn't first break stops the loop after finding the answer? why is it necessary to put second break with the same condition?. even without the break, isn't it suppose to end naturally when a becomes > 333?

I just started learning python yesterday, please help me improve :).

Comment: why do you have a floating `else` after the inner `while`? .... where is the corresponding `if`?

Comment: Because [`while`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-while-statement) can have a `else` statement: "if the expression is false (which may be the first time it is tested) the suite of the else clause, if present, is executed and the loop terminates"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the docs:

> [`break`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-break-statement) terminates the nearest enclosing loop, skipping the optional else clause

This means only your inner `while` loop gets aborted, your outer while loop would continue endlessly.

---

Regarding your question:

> even without the break, isn't it suppose to end naturally when a becomes > 333?

The problem is, when you `break` out of the inner loop, the `else` part does not get executed, so your `a` stays the same. On the next run of the outer loop, the solution is found again, breaking the inner loop, not incrementing `a`...

Comment: that is really helpful :)

Comment: OMGGG NOW I KNOW WHERE IM WRONG THX SO MUCH

Comment: Added why the loop never reaches `a>=333`.

Answer (score 2):

```
 while c > b:
        if a**2 + b**2 == c**2:
            product = a * b * c
            break
        else:
            c += -1
            b += 1
```

`break` breaks the inner loop, it's like saying: *we found what we need, stop calculating more values.*. The outer `while` loop will continue looping after exiting the inner `while` loop. If the condition of `if` is false inside the inner loop, then deduct 1 from `c` and `b`. This deduction will continue up until the condition: `a**2 + b**2 == c**2` is satisfied (true) and hence `break` gets executed or the condition in the inner `while` loop header becomes false.

```
if product > 0:
    break
```

Clearly, whenever `product` is greater than 0, break the outer loop.